# cordova download file in android webview

Tags: javascript, php, android, html, cordova

Is there any way to download a file from a server with cordova android webview?

already tried:

- cordova plugin file-transfer
- cordova plugin file
- <a href=url/to/file / download=filename / file:// cvdf://
- cordova plugin file-downloader
- cordova plugin downloader
- pushing the file from php
- fetching url

I got no errors, it just doesn't work on webview.

Comment: The problem is that android webview (in my case) has just no listener to download files, so I also couldn't come up with a solution... This plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-downloadlistener
claims that they solve it but it also didn't work.. Do you have any progress in the meanwhile?